# Infinite Loop Fetching

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, express

The state restaurants changes from an input form in the front and updates a database in the back. Then the idea is to show the RestaurantList component with the new added restaurant from the input. The idea is not to use the useContext hook. I´ve tried using the useEffect hook to render the list everytime the restaurant state changes, but this makes infinit GET requests in my backend.

```
const RestaurantsList = (props) => {
  const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState("");

  useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/v1/restaurants");
      const data = await response.json();
      setRestaurants(data);
      console.log(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, [restaurants]);

...
```

With this code, the front updates OK and shows the new restaurant, but the back keep making get requests. Why is this happening if the restaurants state isnt changing? Any recommendation? How can I avoid this loop?

I've tried one thing that works and is to remove the preventDefault event when I click the add button. In this way, the page reloads and do what I want but i dont know if it is the best practice:

```
const AddRestaurant = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
  const [priceRange, setPriceRange] = useState("");


 const handleSubmit = async function (e) {
    //e.preventDefault();

    try {
      await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/v1/restaurants", {
        method: "POST",
        made: "cors",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name,
          location,
          price_range: priceRange,
        }),
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    setName("");
    setLocation("");
    setPriceRange("");
  };
 return (
    <div className="mb-4">
      <form action="" on>
        <div className="form-row">
          <div className="col">
            <input
              type="text"
              value={name}
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Name"
              onChange={nameUpdate}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col">
            <input
              className="form-control"
              value={location}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Location"
              onChange={locationUpdate}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col">
            <select
              className="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2"
              value={priceRange}
              onChange={(e) => setPriceRange(e.target.value)}
            >
              <option disabled>Price Range</option>
              <option value="1">$</option>
              <option value="2">$$</option>
              <option value="3">$$$</option>
              <option value="4">$$$$</option>
              <option value="5">$$$$$</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>
            Add
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddRestaurant;
```

Comment: honestly, i still dont get what happens...

Comment: We could just answer everything here on Stackoverflow with "Try to google" couldn't we? @ArenTrot Are you suggesting this is a duplicate? When you get enough rep you can vote to close with that suggestion. Until then, perhaps be a bit friendlier?

Comment: Thx @JNevill! Any suggestion for my question?

Comment: I need some help here. i can´t figure it out....

Answer (score 1):

are you saying that `RestaurantsList()` is throwing the infinite loop? Everything I see here is frontend code. The reason you are getting an infinite loop is because you have a set dependency of `[restaurants]` in your `useEffect` hook. Every time it grabs that data it gets updated, causing it call the function again. If you just want it to fetch the data once then leave the dependency array blank.

Try this:

````
   const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState("");
   
   useEffect(() => {
            const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/restaurants')
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data);
            setRestaurants(data);
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);```
````

Comment: With your solution  it does not work what I want. When I click de Add button on my AddRestaurant component, the database updates, but on the front the DOM dont re render and that new restaurant do not appear on the RestaurantList

Comment: any comment @Ryan??

Comment: so you want it to appear without the page being refreshed is that what you are saying? The component should show the correct data when the page is refreshed.

Comment: correct Ryan. I want to apear without refreshing. I have a list on the screen, I add a new row on the db by a fetch(post) and then I want the list to be updated, but without refreshing.

Comment: if I add the [restaurant] deppendency, it starts to fetch(get the data) in infinite loop...

Comment: the process would be: firstly I fetch(get) the data and show the list. Then I add a new item on a form with a fetch(post), so the db updates  and then i Want that list fetch the new item and shows on screen

Comment: yeah it throws it in an infinite loop because it is always updated, as soon as it grabs the data the component state has changed and therefore it calls it again. So as far as updating the component without refreshing the page, you could create a hook or function that would update the list in the view, for example have on button to add and one to save. That way you can have the most up to date list and then also let the user add what they want and when they hit save you can make a post request and then a get request. I'm just throwing ideas out here. I'm a beginner myself

Comment: but the useEffect hook takes two arguements, a function (the function you want to call) and then an array of dependencies. You can pass in one or many state variables into the array. Whenever the state of the variables in the array change, the function is called

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240187/discussion-between-ryan-speciale-and-miouri).